# IIS 8 Permission of Web Page

Tags: iis-8

I want to have a web page on my website on Windows 2012 R2 server  that only John.Doe can access.  The page is on the test folder and I assigned John.Doe to have Read and Execute permission but I cant access the page with John.Doe credentials on the web browser.

[image]

This type on configuration was working on Windows 2003 server.  Why it didnt work on Windows 2012?  Please help!

TIA

Comment: You can get some basic ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 IIS 6/Windows Server 2003 lacks of many modern security features, so experience from that won't carry over to later Windows releases.

Comment: please mark the post as an answer if it helps you to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run the iis site it runs under the application pool identity, not user the specific user. if you want to run as a specific user you have to assign the custom account in iis application pool identity.

try to use a process monitor to troubleshoot the issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

code to restrict user:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Administrators" />
         </authorization>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authorization/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, my knowledge in IIS is very limited.  How to I assign custom account in application identity?  I only need to give access to John Doe in a particular folder

Comment: if you allow users to access a specific folders then you could use iis authorization rule. check the updated post.

Comment: THank you all for the respnoses.  Appreciate it.  I addedd the IIS_IUSRS and everything if fine now.